# Send Data inside getBody() Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I wrote this code but I cant send data inside getbody() I want to send hashmap but IDE says you must send byte[]. I can't do that please help me.
It's my code a part of volley

```
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Token", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Token_"));
                params.put("Mobile", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Phone_"));
                params.put("Fname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
                params.put("Lname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
                params.put("Email", mEmail_edit_profile.getText().toString().trim());
                aEncodedImage = getStringImage(((BitmapDrawable) mImage_profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
                params.put("Pic", aEncodedImage);
                return params;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getBody():

```
@Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Token", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Token_"));
            params.put("Mobile", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Phone_"));
            params.put("Fname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
            params.put("Lname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
            params.put("Email", mEmail_edit_profile.getText().toString().trim());
            aEncodedImage = getStringImage(((BitmapDrawable) mImage_profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
            params.put("Pic", aEncodedImage);

            ..... (Write the below code here)

            return params;
        }
```

Type this in the place where I've mentioned (Write the below code here)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
out.writeObject(params);
retrun byteOut.toByteArray();
```

Try it..

Comment: data type getbody() is byte[] 
and when our return datatype is ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 0):

You can also use method `getParams()` for sending parameters with your Volley Request which uses Map. Change your code as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Token", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Token_"));
            params.put("Mobile", Sp.getInstance().ReadSP("_Phone_"));
            params.put("Fname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
            params.put("Lname", mName_edit_profile.getText().toString());
            params.put("Email", mEmail_edit_profile.getText().toString().trim());
            aEncodedImage = getStringImage(((BitmapDrawable) mImage_profile.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
            params.put("Pic", aEncodedImage);
            return params;
    }
```

Comment: man i know how can i send with getparam 
our developer beside server languge whant to me send all data via body in volly